# Can an F# project be used as the primary project/host for codedui testing?

Tags: f#, coded-ui-tests

I really don't want to have to add an F# project that is just for my C# coded UI test project to be able to call into. I'd rather do the whole thing in F#.

By adding either a [subtype Guid](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx) or just setting up the program.fs correctly, can an F# project host (doesn't matter if [UIMap.uitest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitest.common.uimap.uimap.aspx) files don't work) a [microsoft codedui test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) and have it show up in VS2015 Test Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I created a standard new F# library and have the following references added:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<Reference Include="mscorlib" />
<Reference Include="FSharp.Core, Version=$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion), Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
```

And this Library1.fs file:

```
namespace CodedUITestProject1

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.Windows.Input
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension

    [<CodedUITest>]
    type CodedUITest1 () =
        [<TestMethod>]
        member this.CodedUITestMethod1() =
            Assert.AreEqual(true, true)
            ()

        [<DefaultValue(false)>]
        val mutable testContext: TestContext
```

and it worked for me:[image: Test Explorer working]